# How do I prevent pushes done from pipelines from triggering CI jobs in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

This question is about Azure Pipelines, but let me start by contrasting it: In GitHub Actions, as long as a workflow uses the provided `$GITHUB_TOKEN` variable to authenticate and push changes back to the repository in which the workflow is running, **this will not trigger more workflows**.

This can be very important in some scenarios where part of the workflow functionality is to make changes to the repository in which it runs, and one workflow could otherwise set off a chain reaction of workflows, all triggering each other. Our scenario fits this description, and I assume GitHub built Actions this way for this very reason.

I have been trying to achieve the same thing in Azure Pipelines, but I cannot figure out how, so I would be thankful for any guidance.

Azure Pipelines has the equivalent of the `$GITHUB_TOKEN` variable — in Azure Pipelines it's called `$(System.AccessToken)`, and you can use this token at the Git level to authenticate against the repository, and interact with the repository subject to any permissions granted to the service account running your pipeline.

But using this provided token does not suppress CI triggers unfortunately.

I have enabled this setting in hopes that it would add this functionality to the job access token:

[image]

But unfortunately it has no effect on this aspect; pushing using the `$(System.AccessToken)` variable still triggers any CI triggers matching the contents of the push.

I know that one can opt out of CI triggers using certain "tags" in commit messages, but this is not a feasible option in our case because the commits are created by external tooling and we do not have full control over the commit message. (And besides those tags in every commit message would pollute the history.)

What am I missing? Is this really not possible to achieve with Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Azure Devops pipelines really aren't designed to work this way. There's nothing special about changes to the repository made by a pipeline or by any other mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

If your pipeline is pushing changes to a code repo, it can [prevent that push from triggering any further CI pipelines by putting `[skip ci]` in the commit message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#skipping-ci-for-individual-pushes).

Comment: Thanks @Vince — I am aware of this (see second to last paragraph in my question) and it is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it's something so simple. Do you have a link to the documentation that explains why this is the case? It would really help with understanding and learning (in case the standard changes in the future)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the trigger type in conditions to disable triggering any CI triggers matching the contents of the push that done from pipelines. Refer to doc [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)

for example:

```
#condition: and(succeeded(),ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'ResourceTrigger'))
condition:and(failed(),in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI'))
```

a YAML pipeline demo:

```
pr:
  - dev2
stages:
- stage: PR
  condition: and(failed(),in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI'))
  displayName: prBuild
  jobs:
   - job: test
     steps:
      - script: echo hello for test job,$(Build.Reason)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked. I'm not looking to disable CI triggers for my pipelines completely, but rather only when pushes are done from another pipeline run using the $(System.AccessToken) token, similar to what GitHub Action does.

Comment: @Daniel Rosenberg. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Xu, thanks again, but the Build.Reason will not be ResourceTrigger in our case, but rather BatchedCI or IndividualCI. We are not using pipeline resource triggers, only CI triggers. Pipeline A will use System.AccessToken to push new commits back to the repo, which will trigger Pipeline B. What we are trying to achieve is to prevent CI triggers from running whenever the pushes are done by a pipeline, similar to the behavior GitHub Actions has built-in.

Comment: To put it another way:
condition: and(failed(),in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI'))

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how that pertains to the scenario I'm describing. I get the feeling you've not really read through the details of my question.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no setting to ignore triggers from specific users or from pipelines settings itself.**

You can use a condition to at the `stage` or `job` scope and check for the kind of trigger as well as the user that triggered the pipeline:

```
- stage:
  condition: not(and (eq (variables['Build.QueuedBy'], '[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts'), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI')))

# or

- job:
  condition: not (and (eq (variables['Build.QueuedBy'], '[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts'), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI')))
```

That will skip the stage/job in case the pipeline was triggered by a different pipeline. It's the fastest way to bail out of a pipeline and prevent anything to run.

Unfortunately, this doesn't exist in "Classic" pipelines (which are defined in the UI). There the only thing you can do is add a first step to bail the job as early as possible:

[image]

[The docs explain the contents of the user account depending on the identity used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values).

Alternatively, you may be able to do a git diff prior to pushing a new commit and only add a new commit in case the new job caused any files to change:

```
& git config --local user.email "jesse.houwing@gmail.com"
& git config --local user.name "Jesse Houwing"
& git diff --exit-code
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    & git add "README.md"
    & git commit -m "Updating classes"
    & git push
}
```

That way even if the job is triggered again, it won't recursively change the file (ask me how I know ;)). But it requires your scripts to be idempotent.